# How can I determine what a shortcut key combination does in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, customization

I have just installed Ubuntu 15.10 and can not unbind `Super<Button2>` from showing me window menu. I bound `Super<Button2>` to resize window, but it still opens windows menu.

How do I determine what some particular shortcut  does in Unity, what program handles it to customize this program in turn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of all the keyboard shortcuts and their brief explanation can be accessed through <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> -> <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd>.

Alternatively , the command line way would be

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys  | less
```

Also you might find useful Ubuntu wiki's [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts) page

As for what handles the shortcuts , that's gnome-settings daemon (in case of GNOME shell) or unity-settings-daemon (in case of unity). The two are related, keybindings are shared, though not entirely.

Comment: I have tried `gsettings list-recursively | grep -ie 'super\|mod4\|win' | grep -v cinnamon | less` but did not found any binding for `Super<Button2>` or something like that. Does it mean this shortcut is hardcoded somewhere in Unity or Compiz?

Comment: Also `Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts` contains not all shortcuts, some shortcuts (like dash button) can be configured with Unity Tweak Tool, but in standard configuration manager.